# Video playback in Unity

Tags: unity

I'm not satisfied with the quality of video playback in Unity (Movie texture which I run after converting video with Miro converter and importing it to Unity),... so, is there any chance that there is a 3rd party library which I can integrate inside Unity to play my movie file? My movie is full HD intro movie to my 3d app which can be played from application menu.

I've tried to use Media Player Classic (MPC) as external application, but the problem is, when I run MPC as new Process from application menu, my menu minimizes and this looks awkward for one stand alone app. When intro finishes, I have to maximize my menu by clicking on application icon placed on Windows taskbar.

Comment: Is the quality of the video playback itself an issue or the quality of the converted video?  Have you tried playing back the converted video in an external app and comparing the results?

Comment: Check out UniSWF, not sure if it works for you... http://www.uniswf.com/home/demo/name/69

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't know what level of freedom you have in selecting external libraries for use in Unity projects, but you might want to look at either:

- The [Windows Media Player SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758070%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which would let you embed a WMP ActiveX control in a form (or presumably anything you could get a HWND to). [Here's a rough example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
- The [DirectShow.Net](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html) library, which exposes the old DirectShow API to C#.

Both of these options may very well be impractical due to the level of control Unity may give you over the lower-level OS objects -- window handles, primarily, and hooks for periodic updates.

Even if you got either of the above options to work, you'd be sacrificing portability (if that matters).

Based on some of the questions floating around Unity Answers ([this one](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/119236/jerky-fullscreen-video-playback.html) and [this one](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/30636/hd-video-playback.html), for example) it looks like video playback is not in an ideal state and may not get there any time soon.

Finally, you may want to browse some of the resources linked in [this external Unity resources question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/7549/what-third-party-tools-and-components-are-availabl.html), which might lead you to something useful for your purposes.

Comment: thanks...I'll think about/try these options and let you know what works. Yes, Unity's movie playback is one of its biggest disadvantages - I just wonder how I can not find any practical solutions on forums.

Answer (score 2):

There is a C# wrapper for the well-known and open-source FFmpeg: http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/